TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') at ./node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/framer.js
In the next  Github Repo I am getting the TypeError:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')     at ./node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/framer.js

based on the code, I believe the issue lies in the framer.js, but I cannot get to this file due to the fact that http2 is not in the node modules, but it is in my package.json.
Dependencies :
{
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.9.0",
    "googleapis": "^135.0.0",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "http2-wrapper": "^2.2.1",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "ml5": "^0.12.2",
    "npm": "^10.5.2",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-p5": "1.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"`
}

config-overrides.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    //do stuff with the webpack config...

    config.resolve.fallback = {
        url: require.resolve('url'),
        assert: require.resolve('assert'),
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
        https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        http2: require.resolve('http2'),
        "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3"),
        net: false,
        fs: false,
        tls: require.resolve('tls'),
        child_process: false,
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),


    };

    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    );

    return config;
}

How would I solve this error, and why is http2 not showing up in the node modules despite being installed.
